# Cypress file upload (image/jpeg)

Tags: file-upload, jpeg, cypress

I am trying to upload a jpeg file in cypress. I am not that familiar with how this is done.

I have the following code:

```
cy.fixture(filename).then(fileContent =>
 {
cy.get('#file').upload({ fileContent, filename, mimeType: 'image/JPEG', })
     { subjectType: 'input' }
    })
```

This is the error I am getting:

One or more field is invalid within given file(s).
Please look into docs to find supported "fileOrArray" values

Comment: There's no official `cy.upload` --- are you using a custom command or a plugin? Also, search for `[cypress] upload` --- there's plenty of questions on this already.

Comment: The `cy.upload` is a plugin

I used the example in this link (https://docs.cypress.io/api/utilities/blob.html#Syntax) and I get the below error :
[cypress-file-upload error]: One or more field is invalid within given file(s).
Please look into docs to find supported "fileOrArray" values

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess you're using this plug [cypress-file-upload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-file-upload) for uploading. Here is its api contract

```
interface FileData {
    fileContent: string;
    fileName: string;
    mimeType: string;
    encoding?: Cypress.Encodings;
  }
    upload(fileOrArray: FileData | FileData[], processingOpts?: FileProcessingOptions): Chainable<Subject>;
```

You made a typo that it should be **fileName**, not **filename**.

Answer (score 2):

Upload image via [cypress-file-upload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-file-upload) works fine. Just convert the image into Blob.

```
const fileName= 'logo.jpeg'
        cy.fixture('logo.jpeg')
        .then(Cypress.Blob.base64StringToBlob)
        .then((fileContent) => {
        cy.get('#new_ad > div:nth-child(19) > div').attachFile(
          {fileContent, fileName, mimeType: 'image/**'},{subjectType: 'drag-n-drop'})
        })
```